# implement feedback in lucene

Tags: lucene

Can someone give me hints to apply pseudo-feedback in lucene. I can not find much help on google. I am using Similarity classes.
Is there any class in lucene which I can extend to implement feedback ?
thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What do you exaclty want to achieve?

Comment: yes, please define "pseudo-feedback"

Comment: By using feedback I want to expand my query. I need some way to expand my query (anyway should be fine)

Comment: I don't know why Lucene hasn't yet supported pseudo-relevance feedback yet... if you don't want to develop too much functionality yourself just use any other IR tool such as Terrier or Indri....

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are referring to [this relevance feedback method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_feedback#Blind_feedback), Once you have the `TopDocs` for your original query, iterate through how ever many (let's say we'll want the top 25 terms for the top 25 docs of the original query) records you desire, and call `IndexReader.getTermVectors(int)`, which will grab the information you need.  Iterate through each. while storing the term frequencies in a hash map would be the implementation the immediately occurs to me.

Something like:

```
//Get the original results
TopDocs docs = indexsearcher.search(query,25);
HashMap<String,ScorePair> map = new HashMap<String,ScorePair>();
for (int i = 0; i < docs.scoreDocs.length; i++) {
    //Iterate fields for each result
    FieldsEnum fields = indexreader.getTermVectors(docs.scoreDocs[i].doc).iterator();
    String fieldname;
    while (fieldname = fields.next()) {
        //For each field, iterate it's terms
        TermsEnum terms = fields.terms().iterator();
        while (terms.next()) {
            //and store it
            putTermInMap(fieldname, terms.term(), terms.docFreq(), map);
        }
    }
}

List<ScorePair> byScore = new ArrayList<ScorePair>(map.values());
Collections.sort(byScore);

BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
//Perhaps we want to give the original query a bit of a boost
query.setBoost(5);
bq.add(query,BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    //Add all our found terms to the final query
    ScorePair pair = byScore.get(i);
    bq.add(new TermQuery(new Term(pair.field,pair.term)),BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
}

//Say, we want to score based on tf/idf
void putTermInMap(String field, String term, int freq, Map<String,ScorePair> map) {
    String key = field + ":" + term;
    if (map.containsKey(key))
        map.get(key).increment();
    else
        map.put(key,new ScorePair(freq,field,term));
}

private class ScorePair implements Comparable{
    int count = 0;
    double idf;
    String field;
    String term;

    ScorePair(int docfreq, String field, String term) {
        count++;
        //Standard Lucene idf calculation.  This is calculated once per field:term
        idf = (1 + Math.log(indexreader.numDocs()/((double)docfreq + 1))) ^ 2;
        this.field = field;
        this.term = term;
    }

    void increment() { count++; }

    double score() {
        return Math.sqrt(count) * idf;
    }

    //Standard Lucene TF/IDF calculation, if I'm not mistaken about it.
    int compareTo(ScorePair pair) {
        if (this.score() < pair.score()) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
}
```

(I make no claim that this is functional code, in it's current state.)

Comment: Using term vectors completely makes sense for retrieving most frequent terms, but I rather think we also need to define the term vector field value while `indexing`.